# Specify "this pc" as initial dir in tkinter open file popup

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm writing a python script that uses tkinter to open a "open file pop up" using the code
`root.filename =  filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/",title = "Select file",filetypes = (("text files","*.txt"),("all files","*.*")))`. I want it to set the initialdir, the directory that is open default to "This PC". Is this possible?

Edit: https://www.quora.com/Where-is-exactly-located-the-This-PC-My-Computer-in-Windows appears to say that this is not possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible.

You can refer to this folder by the `CLSID` key, which is `20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D` and can be viewed in the Registry by this path:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}`

So try this:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.filedialog as filedialog

root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()
root.filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir='::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}',
                                           title='Select file',
                                           filetypes=(('text files', '*.txt'), ('all files', '*.*')))
```

Alternatively, you can reach this virtual path by the [shell shortcut](https://ss64.com/nt/shell.html) `shell:MyComputerFolder`, which is both more meaningful and readable:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.filedialog as filedialog

root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()
root.filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir='shell:MyComputerFolder',
                                           title='Select file',
                                           filetypes=(('text files', '*.txt'), ('all files', '*.*')))
```

Comment: A Windows-only thing? (I might be making a fool of myself due to lack of tkinter exposure. Is the "This PC" entry also an exclusively Windows-thing?)

Comment: @usr2564301, yes, as far as i know it is. Besides I can't think of any alternative or similar implementation of this in another systems (but, fortunately, the only another system that I have right now is macos - the only similar thing is a plain Finder for me), hence this solution is windows-specific.

Comment: May I ask is this method not working now in 2022? I don't know is the problem of Windows or Tkinter. I am using Windows 10 and Tkinter of Python 3.10. When I call `filedialog.askdirectory(initialdir='shell:MyComputerFolder')`, the initial dir is still `C:\Users\User\Documents`.(`'::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}'` the same) Is there any alternative way?

Comment: @Hui Gordon, you're right, but it looks like a specific tinker bug on win10, cause the shell shortcut/guid approach still works when using other tools to bring up standard windows dialogs. You can even paste shell shortcut to standard Windows Explorer - and it still works.

Comment: Both of the above approaches (shell and using guid) do not work on Win10 as of July 11-2022.