# tkinter filedialog initialdir is not accepting shell shortcuts. How can I point the dialog to Downloads folder?

Tags: python, tkinter, windows-10

Running the following code opens a file dialog in the directory of `__main__` instead of "Downloads". I've seen examples of tk using shell shortcuts, so my understanding is this should work.  What am I doing wrong?

```
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename

filepath = askopenfilename(initialdir='shell:Downloads',
                               title='Select File',
                               filetypes=(('csv files', '*.csv'),('all files', '*.*')))
```

I've also tried the following which mirrors an example I found from 2 years ago which supposedly worked, and tried different shell shortcuts, which all act as though an initial dir is not specified:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.filedialog as filedialog
root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()

root.filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir='shell:Downloads',
                               title='Select File',
                               filetypes=(('csv files', '*.csv'),('all files', '*.*')))
```

Python 3.8

TK 8.6.10

My source for using shell shortcuts in accepted answer at:

[Specify "this pc" as initial dir in tkinter open file popup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53566413/14920270)

Comment: Try `initialdir="~/Downloads"`.

Comment: I'm curious what documentation or example led you to believe that "shell:Downloads" would work.

Comment: Thank you. That works for Downloads, which answers my specific question, but I notice it works for some user folders but not others.  Example: ~/Desktop or ~/Pictures doesn't work for me, while ~/Downloads, ~/Documents, ~/Videos, ~/Music all work fine to set initialdir.

Comment: Here is a link to an accepted answer in 2018 to similar question indicating that shell shortcuts work for this:
https://stackoverflow.com/q/53566413/14920270

Comment: `~/Desktop` and `~/Pictures` work for me.

Comment: I also interested where you found  `"shell:Downloads"`.

Comment: You can also try to expand shortcuts `os.path.expanduser('~/Desktop')` - it gives me `/home/furas/Desktop` on Linux. Or using `vars` with `$HOME` instead `user` and `~/` - `os.path.expandvars('$HOME/Desktop')`

Comment: maybe Windows need something like `%UserProfile%\Desktop` with `expandvars`

Comment: @acw1668 I have figured out the issue.  On my system I have Desktop and Pictures sync to MS cloud.  Even though they appear in the same location in File Explorer, for these something like, ~/OneDrive/Desktop was required.  It would be nice to use a one-size-fits option such as shell shortcuts, but at least I think I can accomplish my aim by including code to check for this case.

Comment: @furas see my link in comment above.  I believe I saw at least one other example somewhere, but I have not been able to find it again.  For now it's my only source and it uses "shell:MyComputerFolder" which, like every shell shortcut I tried, did not work.

Comment: I never saw `shell:MyComputerFolder` before (but I don't use `Windows` for years) and I wouldn't use it - only `%UserProfile%\Desktop`, `~/Desktop` or `$HOME/Desktop` (or some modification) with `expandvars` or `expanduser`

Comment: Type `start "" "shell:MyComputerFolder"` into cmd prompt.  Also works with shell:Downloads, etc.